# ignore css in a specific <tr>

Tags: php, html, css

I have this tr

```
<tr style="background-color:'.($count % 2 ? 'rgba(241, 224, 198, 0.6)' : 'rgba(212, 192, 161, 0.6)').';" >
```

and it should work just fine but as you can see on my css (I cannot remove/change this because every page on the site uses this)

```
table tr th, table tr td {
  background: #555555;
  /*color: #FFF; */
  color: skyblue;
  padding: 7px 4px;
  text-align: left;
}

tr.yellow td {
  background: rgb(89, 10, 10);
  padding: 7px 4px;
  text-align: left;
}

table tr td {
  background: rgb(212, 192, 161);
  /*color: #FFF; */
  border-top: 1px solid #FFF;
}
```

tr, td, th and table already have properties... I tried to add this to my css

```
tr.topleveltr {
  background: rgba241, 224, 198, 0.6) !important;
}
tr.topleveltr2 {
  background: rgba(212, 192, 161, 0.6) !important;
}
```

and changed my php tag to `<tr class="'.($count % 2 ? 'topleveltr' : 'topleveltr2').'";>` but It didn't work

is there a way for me to remove css stuff from this ? here's the full code I'm using

```
<div class="Themebox">
    <div id="Topbar" class="Toplevelbox" style="background-image:url(layout/images/global/themeboxes/rankings/top_level_top.gif);">
    <div style="background:url(layout/images/global/themeboxes/rankings/shield.gif);width: 32px;height: 32px;position: relative;margin-left: 5px;margin-top: 1px;"></div>
    <span class="topleveltext">Top Experience</span>
    <div id="RankingBox" class="Themebox2" style="height: auto; display: table; margin-top: -4px;">
    <div id="menusrank"></div>
    <table id="menusrank" style="font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 12px; padding: 0px 12px; height: auto; display: block; background-image:url(layout/images/global/themeboxes/rankings/box-bg.gif); margin-bottom: 5px; margin-top: -6px">
            <?php
                $cache = new Cache('engine/cache/topPlayer');
                if ($cache->hasExpired()) {
                    $players = mysql_select_multi('SELECT `id`, `name`, `level`, `experience`, `looktype`, `lookaddons`, `lookhead`, `lookbody`, `looklegs`, `lookfeet`, ps.value as resets FROM `players` p INNER JOIN  `player_storage` ps ON p.id = ps.player_id WHERE p.deleted = 0 AND p.group_id < 4 AND ps.key=378378 ORDER BY CAST(ps.value AS SIGNED INTEGER) DESC, p.level DESC LIMIT 3;');
                    $cache->setContent($players);
                    $cache->save();
                } else {
                    $players = $cache->load();
                }
                if ($players) {
                $count = 1;
                    foreach ($players as $player) {
                    echo '
                        
                        <tr class="'.($count % 2 ? 'topleveltr' : 'topleveltr2').'";>
                        <td width="34px;" style="padding:0px; padding-left: 2px;">                                      
                            <div><img style="margin-top: -28px; margin-left: -28px;" src="https://outfit-images.ots.me/animatedOutfits1090/animoutfit.php?id='.$player['looktype'].'&addons='.$player['lookaddons'].'&head='.$player['lookhead'].'&body='.$player['lookbody'].'&legs='.$player['looklegs'].'&feet='.$player['lookfeet'].'&g=0&h=3&i=1"></img></div>
                        </td>
                        <td width="130px;" style="padding:1px; padding-left: 3px;">
                        <a class="top_level" href="characterprofile.php?name='.$player['name'].'">
                            <small style="margin-left: -2px;">'.$count.'- </small>'.$player['name'].'
                        </a>';

                        $tooLongName = ((strlen($player['name']) > 17) ? '<img src="layout/images/global/themeboxes/rankings/'.$rankImages[$count].'" style="float: left;margin-top: -36px;margin-left: -4px;">' : '<img src="layout/images/global/themeboxes/rankings/'.$rankImages[$count].'" style="float: left;margin-top: -26px;margin-left: -4px;">');

                        echo '<div class="levelvoctoplevel">
                            <small style="font-size: 10px;">'. ($rankImages[$count] ? $tooLongName : '').'
                            <b> Level: '.$player['level'].'<br> Resets: <font color="green">'.$player['resets'].'</font></b></small>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                        </tr>';
                    $count++;
                }
                }
        ?>
    </table><br>
    <div class="Bottom2" style="background-image:url(layout/images/global/themeboxes/rankings/box-bottom.gif);"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: maybe something like `table tr.topleveltr th, table tr.topleveltr td { background-color: transparent; }`

Comment: Inline Styles cannot be overridden by classes

Comment: _“but It didn't work”_ - your existing stylesheet set background colors for the table _cells_, you tried to set one for the _row_ - of course that won’t work to begin with. (Unless you wanted to see the row background in between table cell spacing only.)

Answer (score 0):

I actually got help in another forum, here's the solution. On my css file

```
table tr:not(.customTable) th, table tr:not(.customTable) td {
  background: #555555;
  /*color: #FFF; */
  color: skyblue;
  padding: 7px 4px;
  text-align: left;
}

tr:not(.customTable).yellow td {
  background: rgb(89, 10, 10);
  padding: 7px 4px;
  text-align: left;
}

table tr:not(.customTable) td {
  background: rgb(212, 192, 161);
  /*color: #FFF; */
  border-top: 1px solid #FFF;
}
```

and then I changed the tag to

```
<tr class="customTable" style="background-color:'.($count % 2 ? 'rgba(241, 224, 198, 0.6)' : 'rgba(212, 192, 161, 0.6)').';" >
```